# How do I get separate legends for separate layers in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, layer

I have a data frame that looks roughly  like df, below.  It's close to what I need, but one legend is printing for all four original grouping categories, rather than just two.  Below, i would like to have one legend that reflects the lines for the "red" and "blue" grouping categories of df1 and then a separate legend that reflects the lines for the "green" and "orange" grouping categories

My motivation is two-fold.  First, I'd like to create a plot that shows that can provide colour for the online publication and be informative in black and white for a printed version. Second, my real data set has 5 grouping categories and really only two (red and blue) are the most informative.

So my solution, which I am attempting to replicate below is to pick out red and blue, make those lines thick, change the linetype of one and make them red and blue colours. And then I'd like to add a second layer with the other, less informative categories and make them thinner and vary them by linetypes. Thanks.

```
test<-rep(c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange'), 6)
test1<-rnorm(24, mean=10, sd=2)
test2<-seq(1,24,2)
df<-data.frame(test, test1, test2)
df1<-subset(df, test=='red'|test=='blue')
df2<-subset(df, test!='red'&test!='blue')

library(ggplot2)
test.plot <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=test2, y=test1, group=test)) + geom_line(aes(col=test,linetype=test), size=2) + scale_color_manual(values=c('red'='red3', 'blue'='darkblue'))
test.plot + geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=test2, y=test1, linetype=test))
```

Comment: But do you want separate legends, or one legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, figure-aspects that represent the same thing need to be in the same legend. Does this solve your issue? It uses three manual scales (color, linetype and size) to get all tests inside one legend, with a specific, discernible line.

```
library(grid) #for unit
library(ggplot2)

#make proper factor levelling in data, easier than setting breaks
df$test <- factor(df$test, levels=c("blue","red","green","orange"))

#plot with a lot of manual scales (but no second sets)
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=test2,y=test1, group=test, col=test)) +
   geom_line(aes(linetype=test,size=test)) +
   scale_color_manual(values=c('red'='red3','blue'='darkblue','green'='black','orange'='black')) +
   scale_linetype_manual(values=c('red'='dashed','blue'='solid','green'='dashed','orange'='dotted')) +
   scale_size_manual(values=c('red'=2,'blue'=2,'green'=0.5,'orange'=0.5)) +
   theme(legend.key.width=unit(3,"lines")) #to show dashes in red
p2
```

[image]

data used (`seed=123`):

```
df <- structure(list(test = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("blue", "red", "green", "orange"), class = "factor"), 
    test1 = c(8.87904870689557, 9.53964502103344, 13.1174166282982, 
    10.1410167828492, 10.2585754703219, 13.4301299737666, 10.9218324119784, 
    7.46987753078693, 8.62629429621295, 9.10867605980008, 12.4481635948789, 
    10.7196276541147, 10.8015429011881, 10.2213654318902, 8.88831773049185, 
    13.5738262736062, 10.9957009564585, 6.06676568674072, 11.4027118031274, 
    9.05441718454413, 7.86435258802631, 9.56405017068341, 7.94799110338552, 
    8.54221754141772), test2 = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 
    19, 21, 23, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23)), .Names = c("test", 
"test1", "test2"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That works just fine, except weirdly the theme(legend.key.width=unit(3, 'lines') argument is giving me the error: "could not find function unit"

Comment: Got it.  The answer is to load  library(grid)